# The degree of field extension $ [\mathbb Q(\alpha):\mathbb Q] $

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> I'm trying to see how 
>   $$ [\mathbb Q(\alpha):\mathbb Q]=4,$$
>   where
>   $$ \alpha^5 = 1,\ \alpha \neq 1 .$$

I don't understand why it's 4 and not 5.

From my knowledge the basis could be

$$ {1, \sqrt[5]{1}, \sqrt[5]{1^2}, \sqrt[5]{1^3}, \sqrt[5]{1^4}} $$

Why isn't this the case?

Help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: This is a cyclotomic extension. You are adjoining a primitive 5th root of unity, and the minimal polynomial for this $\alpha$ is actually $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$. The degree of a cyclotomic extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ is always $\phi(n)$, where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function, and $n$ is the degree of $\alpha$. In this case, $\phi(5)=4$.

Comment: @Sunyata thanks, To calculate that polynomial don't I need to recognise that the degree in question is 4? That's what I'm struggling with here, but I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: For $p$-th roots of unity where $p$ is prime, the minimal polynomial is always $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\ldots+x+1$.

Comment: If you have access to Dummit and Foote 3rd edition, see sections 13.6 and 14.5.

Comment: All of your five 'basis' elements are equal to $1$; do you mean $1$, $\alpha$, $\alpha^2$, $\alpha^3$, $\alpha^4$? (And that's not a basis because if you add them, you get $0$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element $\alpha$ clearly satisfies $f(x) = x^5-1$. However, this polynomial factors over $\mathbb{Q}$:
$$f(x) = x^5-1 = (x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1).$$
Since $\alpha\neq 1$, then $\alpha$ must in fact be a root of
$$\Phi_5(x) = x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1.$$
This already proves that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]\leq 4$. The question is whether $\Phi_5$ is irreducible. You may already know it is (there is a standard proof using Eistenstein’s Criterion). This fits into the general theory of *Cyclotomic extensions* of $\mathbb{Q}$, as noted by Sunyata.

Comment: Thank you, that does answer my question, but I have slight doubts over why the basis in my question is wrong. Is it because 1 isn't prime?

Comment: @Ravi: No, it’s because there is in fact a linear relation between your elements (even setting aside that there is ambiguity about what $\sqrt[5]{1}$ even means... there are five complex numbers that satisfy $x^5=1$, but $\sqrt[5]{1}$ usually denotes the **real** one (namely, $1$). If $\zeta$ is a complex nonreal root, then $\zeta^4+\zeta^3+\zeta^2+\zeta^1+1 =0$, giving the linear dependence among your five elements.

Comment: Thanks, so if p prime,  $ \sqrt[N]{p}, ... , \sqrt[N]{p^(N-1)} $
are always linearly independent correct? But if p is not prime, that isn't always (ever?) the case?

Comment: @Ravi: It has **nothing** to do with whether $p$ is prime. What matter is whether $N$ is prime. Do look up “cyclotomic extensions”, please.

Comment: I will, thanks for your help